# Get firmware version for InfiniBand adapter from QLogic

Tags: debian, infiniband, hba, pci

How can I find the correct firmware version number for a QLogic InfiniBand adapter on a Debian server?

`ibstat` displays an empty version number like so:

```
Firmware version: 
Hardware version: 2
```

`lspci -vvv` is also silent on the issue like so:

```
InfiniBand: QLogic Corp. IBA7322 QDR InfiniBand HCA (rev 02)
Subsystem: QLogic Corp. IBA7322 QDR InfiniBand HCA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [QConvergeConsole CLI](http://filedownloads.qlogic.com/Files/TempDownlods/86267/UsersGuide_QCC_CLI_SN0054667-00H.pdf) with the `-df` switch solved the problem.